# How to return data from Backend to Frontend in Wix Corvid

Tags: javascript, velo

I'm trying to return few data from backend to frontend once the registration is complete. While testing I can see that the user gets registered successfully but for some reason, the data I return from the backend method to the frontend comes with "undefined".

Below is my Backend Code.

```
export function doRegistration(email, password, firstName, lastName) {
    wixUsersBackend.register(email, password, {
        "contactInfo": {
            "firstName": firstName,
            "lastName": lastName
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.status === "Pending") {
            wixUsersBackend.approveByToken(result.approvalToken)
                .then((token) => {
                    return {
                        "approved": true,
                        "userId": result.user.id,
                        "isEmailExist": false
                    }
                }).catch((err) => {
                    return {
                        "approved": false,
                        "isEmailExist": false,
                        "errorCode": err.errorCode,
                        "errorMessage": err.errorDescription
                    }
                });
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        return {
            "approved": false,
            "isEmailExist": true
        }
    });
}
```

I tried reading the return value from frontend in both the ways as follow:

```
doRegistration($w('#txtLoginEmail').value, $w('#txtPassword').value, $w('#txtFirstName').value, $w('#txtLastName').value).then(result => {
                if (result.approved) { //.approved is undefined
}
});
```

Also,

```
let result = doRegistration($w('#txtLoginEmail').value, $w('#txtPassword').value, $w('#txtFirstName').value, $w('#txtLastName').value);
if (result.approved) {  //.approved is undefined
}
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jilu

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are not catering for a scenario where the result.status is not "Pending" Try the below

```
if (result.status === "Pending") {
      wixUsersBackend.approveByToken(result.approvalToken)
      .then((token) => {
           return {
              "approved": true,
              "userId": result.user.id,
              "isEmailExist": false
           }
           }).catch((err) => {
               return {
                  "approved": false,
                  "isEmailExist": false,
                  "errorCode": err.errorCode,
                  "errorMessage": err.errorDescription
               }
           });
} else {
      return {
         "approved": true,
         "userId": result.user.id,
         "isEmailExist": false
       }
}
```